# Why don't Rails 4 send mail in development mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not understanding how to trouble shoot my settings.  I'm using devise with the ansync settings with sidekiq to send email.  Everything is working in production but I'm having trouble triggering mail in development mode, which I'd like to do to play around with a few features. I've seen other posts on this topic and am generally under the impression that I need to be setting

`config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true`

my setup in `development.rb` currently looks like

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'localhost'
  }
```

How can I trouble shoot this further?

I'm near certain that email is getting processed correctly by sidekiq based on watching my sidekiq logs,

[image: https://cl.ly/image/1N403B1o2S34/Image%202014-12-10%20at%209.39.52%20AM.png]

I think there could be a problem with my Sendgrid settings, but I'm using the same settings in production and not having any issue so I'm still thinking there is an issue with sending in development.

Comment: Do you have environment variables `SENDGRID_USERNAME` and `SENDGRID_PASSWORD` in your local environment?

Comment: I don't think your domain can be "localhost" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439381/what-is-the-domain-symbol-referring-to-when-configuring-action-mailer

Comment: Mailgun provides us with a domain we use to connect to it. We actually have two ... one for staging and dev and one for production. SendGrid, when we were investigating it, seems awfully similar to Mailgun - or perhaps Mailgun is similar to them ;). You may well have a domain from SendGrid that you can use in the `domain: ` key/value pair from your local/dev setup to connect to their service.

Comment: I feel like my problems were rooted in not having a default to: setup in devise, which actually I had set but think there may have been a problem with how spring was interacting with my env variables.  Either way, things are working now.